# How to get the bounding box (meters) of an entire Unity gameobject, including all its child objects

Tags: unity, scale

How do you get the **meter-accurate bounding box** of an entire Unity GameObject, including all its child objects? *It seems encapsulate bounds does not generate the right units at all*

```
    bounds = new Bounds ();
    Renderer[] renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer> ();
    foreach (Renderer renderer in renderers)
    {
        bounds.Encapsulate (renderer.bounds);
    }
```

I've tried using encapsulate bounds on a round cushion with only a single child object containing 1 renderer.

- Bounds encapsulate above gives
  `(10.3037,10.17837,10.30449)`
- Just squooshing a Unity cube to size it gives
  `(0.6185507,0.1842149,0.6185507)`

A round cushion as you know is small on one side, so the bounds result isn't accurate.

How does one script a result closer to the second result above?

Comment: Did you mean to include the origin in your bounds by starting with `new Bounds()`?

Comment: that seems to work! was in the process of trying out mesh.bounds instead of renderer.bounds ... do you know if one is more accurate than the other?

Comment: One is relative to the source mesh (so 0 is the mesh's pivot), the other is relative to the renderer's transformation in the world (so 0 is the center of the world).